# hudson unit test configuration with perl

Tags: perl, junit, hudson

I managed to setup Hudson. But there are a few things which are really confusing me. The Hudson and the SVN repository are both in the same machine as I am learning Hudson.

repository URL configured in Hudson is `file:///svnrepos/svnproj`

The build job name is `Unittest`

my svn repository checkout is located at `/home/anand/svnprojcopy/svnproj`.

It has following files

```
./lib/operatingsystem.pm
./t/operatingsystem.t
./Build (generated from Build.PL script)
```

I have configured the Poll SCM option with * * * * *

For build option I have configured execute shell option with

```
cd /home/anand/svnprojcopy/svnproj;prove -I ./lib -v --harness=TAP::Harness::JUnit
```

which generates `junit_output.xml`

I have configured `Publish JUnit test result report` with Test report XMLs `junit_output.xml`

But every time I force to build it report "No test results configured". I believe it isn't looking into `/home/anand/svnprojcopy/svnproj` for `junit_output.xml` but in `/var/lib/hudson/jobs/Unittest/workspace`

I am not sure whether I have setup Hudson properly or not as I am not sure how to configure paths. I manually copied the file junit_output.xml to var/lib/hudson/jobs/Unittest/workspace and it reports that it found the file but the results aren't the latest. I am sure I am missing something basic here. Can someone help me out please.

Comment: The console output is as follows:                                                            
t/operationsystem.t .. 
ok 1 - use operatingsystem;
ok 2 - require operatingsystem;
ok 3 - get_os() test
1..3
ok
All tests successful.
Files=1, Tests=3, 0.0210161 wallclock secs ( 0.01 usr  0.00 sys +  0.01 cusr  0.00 csys =  0.02 CPU)
Result: PASS
Recording test results
No test report files were found. Configuration error?
[DEBUG] Skipping watched dependency update for build: Unittest #38 due to result: FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 1):

It was simple mistake. I didn't add the testfolder 't' to svn. Hence when I tried to run 'prove -I ./lib -v --harness=TAP::Harness::JUnit' in the hudson shell command, the command was failing. Now after adding to svn, the path /var/lib/hudson/jobs/Unitest/workspace is updated with the svn copy and prove command generated the junit_output.xml successfully.